# How do I test with jest that a list of Enums in TypeScript has all the string values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a list of enums:

```
export enum Hobbies {
   Paint = 'PAINT',
   Run = 'RUN',
   Bike = 'BIKE',
   Dance = 'DANCE'
}
```

I'd like to loop through this in Jest and assert that all the string values are there, maybe along with each key too? This is in case a value is null/missing and that could affect the behavior of a UI render.

I was thinking import the list, and assert that each value is not null. But do I use a test.each()? This list is actually much longer.

I know enums shouldn't need a test like this but in this case it is useful.

Comment: To recommend the best approach, it might be helpful to know *why* a test like this is useful in your case. As you imply, it is invariably true that an enum's keys exist and have their values. Do you want to guard against future deletions of keys or changes to values?

Comment: This should have been covered by TS. It will cause an error if a key in use  isn't there, won't it?

Comment: @kdau Yes that's correct. It is quite a long list so I want to guard it against future possible changes to the values. How might I go about writing the test for this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Property Matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#property-matchers) of snapshot testing. Whenever the enumeration value changes, the test will fail if the two snapshots do not match.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
export enum Hobbies {
  Paint = 'PAINT',
  Run = 'RUN',
  Bike = 'BIKE',
  Dance = 'DANCE',
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { Hobbies } from './';

describe('67755520', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(Hobbies).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
      Object {
        "Bike": "BIKE",
        "Dance": "DANCE",
        "Paint": "PAINT",
        "Run": "RUN",
      }
    `);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks! Is there a way to explicitly have a dynamic test? Using for..in for example and then check that when I pass that enum value it has a corresponding value?